# how to convert array to mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Does anyone know how I can pull the currency (`isoAlphaCode`) and `sellNote` from the following array and add it to MySQL database?

```
Array
(
    [wrappedObject] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [baseCurrency] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 826
                            [description] => Great British Pound
                            [isoAlphaCode] => GBP
                        )

                    [fxCurrency] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 978
                            [description] => Euro
                            [isoAlphaCode] => EUR
                        )

                    [buyNote] => 6.1
                    [sellNote] => 1.1495
                    [buyCheque] => 9.6
                    [sellCheque] => 
                    [rank] => HIGH
                    [denominations] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 20
                            [1] => 50
                            [2] => 100
                            [3] => 200
                        )

                    [degradation] => 5
                    [upsellingDenomination] => 20
                    [collectionOrderDenominations] => 
                    [isExotic] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [baseCurrency] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 826
                            [description] => Great British Pound
                            [isoAlphaCode] => GBP
                        )

                    [fxCurrency] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 840
                            [description] => US Dollar
                            [isoAlphaCode] => USD
                        )

                    [buyNote] => 6
                    [sellNote] => 1.2268
                    [buyCheque] => 9.6
                    [sellCheque] => 
                    [rank] => HIGH
                    [denominations] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 10
                            [1] => 20
                            [2] => 50
                            [3] => 100
                        )

                    [degradation] => 1
                    [upsellingDenomination] => 20
                    [collectionOrderDenominations] => 
                    [isExotic] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [baseCurrency] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 826
                            [description] => Great British Pound
                            [isoAlphaCode] => GBP
                        )

                    [fxCurrency] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 36
                            [description] => Australian Dollar
                            [isoAlphaCode] => AUD
                        )

                    [buyNote] => 5.95
                    [sellNote] => 1.6201
                    [buyCheque] => 5.95
                    [sellCheque] => 
                    [rank] => LOW
                    [denominations] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 20
                            [1] => 50
                        )

                    [degradation] => 5
                    [upsellingDenomination] => 20
                    [collectionOrderDenominations] => 
                    [isExotic] => 1
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [baseCurrency] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 826
                            [description] => Great British Pound
                            [isoAlphaCode] => GBP
                        )

                    [fxCurrency] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 48
                            [description] => Bahraini Dinar
                            [isoAlphaCode] => BHD
                        )

                    [buyNote] => 8.7
                    [sellNote] => 0.4456
                    [buyCheque] => 
                    [sellCheque] => 
                    [rank] => LOW
                    [denominations] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 10
                            [1] => 20
                        )

                    [degradation] => 1
                    [upsellingDenomination] => 1
                    [collectionOrderDenominations] => 
                    [isExotic] => 1
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [baseCurrency] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 826
                            [description] => Great British Pound
                            [isoAlphaCode] => GBP
                        )

                    [fxCurrency] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 52
                            [description] => Barbados Dollar
                            [isoAlphaCode] => BBD
                        )

                    [buyNote] => 9.7
                    [sellNote] => 2.324
                    [buyCheque] => 
                    [sellCheque] => 
                    [rank] => LOW
                    [denominations] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 20
                            [1] => 50
                            [2] => 100
                        )

                    [degradation] => 2
                    [upsellingDenomination] => 2
                    [collectionOrderDenominations] => 
                    [isExotic] => 1
                )

        )

    [valid] => 1
    [errorMessage] => 
    [errorCauses] => 
)
```

Comment: Where does the "following array" come from?

Comment: from a json file

Comment: That's a `print_r` of a PHP array... Where does the JSON come into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = json_decode('{"wrappedObject":[{"baseCurrency":{"id":826,"description":"Great British Pound","isoAlphaCode":"GBP"}...', true);

echo $arr["wrappedObject"][0]["baseCurrency"]["isoAlphaCode"]; // outputs "GBP"
```

Use this bit of code.

It uses the `json_decode` method that you have been using already. Just make sure you set the second parameter to `true`.
What that will do is store the JSON as an [array rather than an object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#refsect1-function.json-decode-parameters).

### Update

Following @user2401723 comment below.

I don't fully understand what you are storing in the JSON, but it seems that you take the user's base currency (I assume the currency of their country) and that is stored as `"baseCurrency"` and repeated in each property in the object.

Consider this line of code.

```
echo $arr["wrappedObject"][0]["baseCurrency"]["isoAlphaCode"]; // outputs "GBP"
echo $arr["wrappedObject"][0]["sellNote"]; // outputs 1.1495
```

This outputs the user's base currency.

Since `[0]` is the Euro (obtained by writing `$arr["wrappedObject"][0]["fxCurrency"]["isoAlphaCode"]`), then I assume the `sellNote` is the exchange rate between `baseCurrency` and `fxCurrency`.

I don't know how you want to use the data but I will write a simple for loop so you can see all the `isoAlphaCode`s and the `sellNote`s.

```
// this first line will display your base currency
echo $arr["wrappedObject"][0]["baseCurrency"]["isoAlphaCode"];
// this for loop will display every currency code and their exchange rate (if that's what sellNote is)
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr["wrappedObject"]); $i++)
{
    echo $arr["wrappedObject"][$i]["fxCurrency"]["isoAlphaCode"];
    echo $arr["wrappedObject"][$i]["sellNote"];
}
```

#### MySQLi

Regards to inserting it into the MySQL, I don't know whether you are using PDO or MySQLi so I will give you an example of MySQLi.

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "myDBname";

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr["wrappedObject"]); $i++)
{
    $isoAlphaCode = $arr["wrappedObject"][$i]["fxCurrency"]["isoAlphaCode"];
    $sellNote     = $arr["wrappedObject"][$i]["sellNote"];

    $query = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO myTable(isoAlphaCode, sellNote) VALUES(?, ?)");  
    $query->bind_param("sd", $isoAlphaCode, $sellNote);
    $query->execute();
}
$query->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

**Line by line:**

1. `$dbhost` - The host of your database.
2. `$dbuser` - The username of your database.
3. `$dbpass` - The password for your database.
4. `$dbname` - The name of your database.
5. Newline.
6. `$mysqli = new mysqli(...)` - Creating the MySQLi object. See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php). This will store our connection to the database.
7. Newline.
8. `for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr["wrappedObject"]); $i++)` - Since all of the currencies are stored under `$arr["wrappedObject"]` we access this index and then [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to determine the length.
9. Opening code block.
10. `$isoAlphaCode` - Store the currency `isoAlphaCode` in this variable. We are referencing the `$i` index in the array.
11. `$sellNote` - The [float](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) exchange rate .
12. Newline.
13. `$mysqli->prepare("... VALUES(?, ?")` - The [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).
    It is extremely important to use prepared statements since it will [prevent SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).
    `?` Tells the query that we are going to insert data here.
14. `bind_param("sd", $isoAlphaCode, $sellNote)` - Add our parameters to the query.
    `"sd"` - tells the query that our first `?` is a `string` and the second is a `double`. Then we simply list our parameters after this in the order that relates to the `?`.
15. `$query->execute()` - execute the query.
16. Closing code block.
17. `$query->close()` - Close the query
18. `$mysqli->close()` - Close the connection (only once finished with it).

Comment: Thanks but how do you get isoAlphaCode and sellNote for each currency ?